# How do I remove HTML that I place dynamically with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

So I am adding text and textbox to a page dynamically if a checkbox is selected.  However, the  dynamic part is that the code behind is creating a CheckBoxList and appending text from a Code table to each checkbox.  Therefore, I am looking for any checkbox with the ID that contains "chkCheckBox".  From there, I can check if the  next to the checkbox is "Other" and if so insert the line of HTML in the last line below.

```
    $("input:checkbox[id*=chkSomeCheckBox]").click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().html() == "Other") {
            $("<span> : </span><input type='textbox'>").insertAfter($(this).next());
        }
    });
```

PROBLEM: The problem I am having is obviously if they uncheck the box, it appends ANOTHER textbox next to the first one, and this continues.

Help: I am having problems figuring out how to check if they are putting a check in the checkbox and only place the HTML if true.  Secondly, if they uncheck the checkbox that meets the condition of ( == "Other) then remove the textbox I dynamically placed.

I figure its going to use the JQuery "remove()" event, but I am not sure how to tie in (this) with the :checked selector.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:checkbox[id*=chkSomeCheckBox]").click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().html() == "Other" && $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("<span> : </span><input type='textbox'>").insertAfter($(this).next());
        }
        else if($(this).next().html() == "Other"){
           $(this).next().empty();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox[id*=chkSomeCheckBox]").click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().html() == "Other" && $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("<span> : </span><input type='textbox'>").insertAfter($(this).next());
        }
        else if($(this).next().html() == "Other"){
           // remove html
        }
});
```

that said try to think about better ways you could do this... this seems a little bit "round the houses" as it were. :p I'm sure there must be easier ways.